# mutt showing headers in email content when emailed from crontab output

Tags: cron, mutt

When I'm sending an email using mutt (output of a script from cron/cronie) I get the following lines at the beginning of my email:

```
To: myemail@myemail.com
Subject: Cron <root@alarm> /home/alarm/bin/script-name.sh
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=ANSI_X3.4-1968
Auto-Submitted: auto-generated
Precedence: bulk
X-Cron-Env: <LANG=C>
X-Cron-Env: <SHELL=/bin/bash>
X-Cron-Env: <PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin>
X-Cron-Env: <MAILTO=myemail@myemail.com>
X-Cron-Env: <HOME=/root>
X-Cron-Env: <LOGNAME=root>
X-Cron-Env: <USER=root>

remainder of email from output of script..
```

**EDIT**: mutt gets called from the `cronie.service` file on this line:

`ExecStart=/usr/bin/crond -n -m mutt`

```
$ cat ~/.muttrc 
set sendmail="/usr/bin/msmtp"
set use_from=yes
set realname="Ikwyl6"
set from=ikwyl6@myemail.com
set envelope_from=yes
```

Does anyone know why I'm getting these headers in the content of the email?

Comment: can you add the crontab line ?

Comment: which OS version ?

Comment: @EchoMike444 - I don't have a '| mutt myemail@email.com' cron line. I have the cronie.service file that starts the cronie service/daemon and that uses mutt for the mta to send the email if there is any output from the cron item. I'm on arch linux: Linux alarm 4.4.192-1-ARCH #1 PREEMPT Wed Sep 11 03:22:52 UTC 2019 armv5tel GNU/Linux

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `cronie.service` file put:

```
Environment="EMAIL=youremail@email.com"
```

where `EMAIL` is the email that you want your cron job (output only from cron scripts) to be emailed.

Change the line in `cronie.service` that has:
`ExecStart=/usr/bin/crond -n -m 'msmtp -t'` to:

`ExecStart=/usr/bin/crond -n -m 'mutt -H - ${EMAIL}'`

Where `-H -` takes the start of the piped input to mutt as the headers of the file and the body of the message.

In your /etc/cron.d/ file or crontab file, add:

`MAILFROM=youremail@domain.tld`

restart cronie `sudo systemctl restart cronie`

Answer (score 0):

**Awswer to your question:**

The cron service adds environment of your script as custom e-mail headers. That's normal behaviour.

**How to hide it?**

Look into your mutt config. If there're none **ignore** or **unignore** lines you can add:

```
ignore          *
unignore        From To Cc Bcc Date Subject
```

see [selecting headers in neomuttrc(5)](https://neomutt.org/guide/configuration.html#11-2-%C2%A0selecting-headers)

> ignore pattern [ pattern ... ]
>
> unignore { * | pattern ... }
>
> ```
>    The ignore command allows you to specify header fields which you don't normally
>    want to see in the pager. You do not need to specify the full header field name.
>    For  example,  "ignore  content-"  will
>    ignore all header fields that begin with the pattern "content-", "ignore *" will
>    ignore all headers.
>
>    To remove a previously added token from the list, use the unignore command. For
>    example, "unignore *" will remove all tokens from the ignore list.
> ```